# Using java code in pnml to represent Colored Petri Net

Tags: java, automation, modeling, petri-net, dining-philosopher

When we write a Colored Petri Net (CP-Net), can we use java code in the declaration section like the following example in PNML, or we have to consider a standard in this part also?
the following example is an XML representation, but can we use the same way to represent it in pnml? if no,can you help me how can we do so?
thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<pnml>
  <net id="n1">
    <import>
      <text>import java.util.Iterator;</text>
    </import>
    <declaration>
      <text>int x = 1;

    public String left(int i) {
        String s = "";
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                s = new String("b");
                break;
            case 2:
                s = new String("c");
                break;
            case 3:
                s = new String("d");
                break;
            case 4:
                s = new String("e");
                break;
            case 5:
                s = new String("f");
                break;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public String right(int i) {
        String s = "";
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                s = new String("a");
                break;
            case 2:
                s = new String("b");
                break;
            case 3:
                s = new String("c");
                break;
            case 4:
                s = new String("d");
                break;
            case 5:
                s = new String("e");
                break;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public TokenSet lr(int i) {
        TokenSet tk = new TokenSet(new Token(right(i)));
        tk.add(new Token(left(i)));
        return tk;
    }</text>
    </declaration>
    <place id="p3">
      <graphics>
        <position x="475" y="325"/>
      </graphics>
      <name>
        <text>free forks</text>
        <graphics>
          <offset x="70" y="0"/>
        </graphics>
      </name>
      <initialMarking>
        <text>"a"</text>
        <text>"b"</text>
        <text>"c"</text>
        <text>"d"</text>
        <text>"e"</text>
      </initialMarking>
    </place>
    <place id="p2">
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="335"/>
      </graphics>
      <name>
        <text>eat</text>
        <graphics>
          <offset x="50" y="-10"/>
        </graphics>
      </name>
    </place>
    <place id="p1">
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="125"/>
      </graphics>
      <name>
        <text>think</text>
        <graphics>
          <offset x="60" y="-10"/>
        </graphics>
      </name>
      <initialMarking>
        <text>1</text>
        <text>2</text>
        <text>3</text>
        <text>4</text>
        <text>5</text>
      </initialMarking>
    </place>
    <arc id="o15" source="t5" target="p3">
      <expression>
        <text>lr(x)</text>
      </expression>
      <graphics>
        <position x="331" y="440"/>
        <position x="454" y="341"/>
      </graphics>
    </arc>
    <arc id="o7" source="t5" target="p1">
      <expression>
        <text>x</text>
      </expression>
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="450"/>
        <position x="325" y="515"/>
        <position x="185" y="515"/>
        <position x="185" y="75"/>
        <position x="325" y="75"/>
        <position x="325" y="99"/>
      </graphics>
    </arc>
    <arc id="o9" source="t4" target="p2">
      <expression>
        <text>x</text>
      </expression>
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="230"/>
        <position x="325" y="309"/>
      </graphics>
    </arc>
    <arc id="i17" source="p2" target="t5">
      <expression>
        <text>getTokenSet().size()&gt;0</text>
      </expression>
      <expression>
        <text>x = (Integer) (getTokenSet().get(0)).getObject()</text>
      </expression>
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="361"/>
        <position x="325" y="440"/>
      </graphics>
    </arc>
    <arc id="i11" source="p3" target="t4">
      <expression>
        <text>getTokenSet().size()&gt;0</text>
      </expression>
      <expression>
        <text>lr(x)</text>
      </expression>
      <graphics>
        <position x="453" y="310"/>
        <position x="332" y="230"/>
      </graphics>
    </arc>
    <arc id="i13" source="p1" target="t4">
      <expression>
        <text>getTokenSet().size()&gt;0</text>
      </expression>
      <expression>
        <text>x</text>
      </expression>
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="151"/>
        <position x="325" y="220"/>
      </graphics>
    </arc>
    <transition id="t4">
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="225"/>
      </graphics>
      <name>
        <text>take forks</text>
        <graphics>
          <offset x="-70" y="0"/>
        </graphics>
      </name>
      <guard>
        <text>boolean found = false;
            Iterator it = p1.getTokens().iterator();
            while (!found &amp;&amp; it.hasNext()) {
                Token token = (Token) it.next();
                int i = (Integer) token.getObject();
                if (p3.getTokens().containsAll(lr(i))) {
                    x = i;
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            return found;</text>
      </guard>
    </transition>
    <transition id="t5">
      <graphics>
        <position x="325" y="445"/>
      </graphics>
      <name>
        <text>put down forks</text>
        <graphics>
          <offset x="-70" y="0"/>
        </graphics>
      </name>
      <guard>
        <text>return true;</text>
      </guard>
    </transition>
  </net>
</pnml>
```

Comment: what are you going to do with the model? CPN-Tools accept only CPNML.

Comment: I want to build a tool to generate java code represents CP-Net described in pnml file, but in fact It' not clear for me how can I write the declaration section in pnml file.

Comment: I mean It's not clear for me if there is any other way to write a declaration as in the above example in pnml, is there any standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution, We can't use the same way, we can use languages like **[MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML)** (a subset of MathML) to consider the standard.
[www.pnml.org/papers/forte06.pdf](http://www.pnml.org/papers/forte06.pdf)

Thanks for all comments..